# Can Proboscis be used with Pytest?

Tags: pytest, proboscis

I have pytest as my test runner in PyCharm, but when I try launching [Proboscis](https://pythonhosted.org/proboscis/) from a Pytest test, it doesn't recognize Pytest annotations.

**run_tests.py**

```
def run_tests():
    from proboscis import TestProgram
    import test_pytest_param

    # Run Proboscis and exit.
    TestProgram().run_and_exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Instead of running as main, try to run tests with pytest
    pass 

def test_run_proboscis_as_pytest():
    run_tests()
```

**test_pytest_param.py**

```
import pytest


def is_negative(n):
    return n < 0

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x",[7, -7])
def test_is_negative(x):
    assert is_negative(x)
```

This fails with `TypeError: test_is_negative() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

Can I run Pytest with Proboscis somehow, maybe with the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I communicated with the author of Proboscis and he wrote that it cannot be run with PyTest. A plugin for PyTest would make more sense than porting Proboscis since PyTest works so different from Nose / UnitTest.